# How to Get the Column Value in Newline in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

I have the following Requirement:

`Emp` table have the following `3 columns`,

`Id , Name and programming`

```
Id   Name   Programming 
-- ---- ---------------
1    Raju   Java,Plsql,sql 
2    Kamal  C,C++,Java 
-------------------------
```

I need the following output as shown below:

```
Id        Name                 Programming 
--------------------------------------------
1         Raju                     Java 
                                   plsql 
                                   sql 
2         kamal                     c 
                                    c++ 
                                   Java. <code>
------------------------------------------------
```

The `Id` is `1` and the `Name` is `Raja` then the programming is `Java`,
in the next line there should `not` be any `value for id and Name` but 
 for `programming` there should be Plsql and in next row also same no value.

For `Id` and `Name` then for programming it should be `Sql`.

Can anyone suggest me the code to get the above format? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to create a collection from the coma delimited string :

1) create the type;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "TNA_STRMANIPTYPE" as table of varchar2(4000)
/
```

2)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function str_manipulation
  ( p_str in varchar2,
    p_delim in varchar2 default ',' )
  return tna_strManipType
  AS
     v_str long default p_str || p_delim;
     v_n   number;
     v_data tna_strManipType := tna_strManipType();
  BEGIN
      LOOP
          v_n := instr( v_str, p_delim );
          exit when (nvl(v_n,0) = 0);
          v_data.extend;
          v_data(v_data.count) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(v_str,1,v_n-1)));
          v_str := substr( v_str, v_n+1 );
      END LOOP;
      RETURN v_data;
END;
```

Now you you can use this collection as a table :

```
SELECT column_value 
  FROM TABLE(str_manipulation('Java,Plsql,sql'))
```

and using this function and casting it to a table, you will need to handle the rest of the insert part for your needs :)